# PHP How to retrieve value from returned object

Tags: php, oop

Upon successful call, an object method returns the following which is captured in $responseVar.

```
Array (
    [0] => myClass Object
        (
            [id] => 123456789
            [success] => 1
        )

)
```

If I try to reference the value by array

```
echo $responseVar['id'];
```

Error returns as 'Cannot use object of type stdClass as array'. If I try to reference it as object

```
echo $responseVar->$id;
```

I get errors 'Undefined variable: id' and 'Trying to get property of non-object'.

I can always convert the response to JSON, but is there another way to directly reference the value of ID and success?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use this:

(Here i access the array index 0 and there property id)

```
echo $responseVar[0]->id;
```